# How to run tnftpd without root on OS X?

Tags: osx, ftp, daemon, file-server, netbsd

I'm trying to run `tnftpd` on OS X, which is NetBSD's FTP server and used to be OS X's FTP server. I built and installed it from [Apple's sources](https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/lukemftpd/lukemftpd-51.tar.gz). Unfortunately, it seems that I cannot run the server without root privileges. These have been my approaches so far to get the server to work without root privileges:

- I've tried changing the port number via the `-P` option, to ensure
  that it uses no privileged ports.
- I've tried fiddling with config files, such as `ftpd.conf` and
  `ftpusers`.
- I've also tried the `-r` option (which disallows root privileges once a
  user logs in).

All of these attempts have been to no avail.

Some examples to illustrate my attempts:

```bsh
$ ftpd -lnD  # exit code is 0, but `ps' shows no server running
```

```bsh
$ ftpd -lnDr # supposed to drop root privileges, but same as above
```

```bsh
$ # let's try running on a different port...
$ ftpd -lnDr -P 50001 # exit code still 0, but no dice
```

However, if I try something like this (this is a scenario where I have no custom configurations in place):

```bsh
$ sudo ftpd -lnD
Password:
$ ps aux | grep -i ftpd
root            21998   0.0  0.0  4298888    720   ??  Ss   10:41PM   0:00.00 ftpd -lnD
```

I have no problems.

How can I run the `tnftpd` server without root privileges? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the man page `tnftpd(8)`

```
                                                            ... The server
 uses the TCP protocol and listens at the port specified in the ``ftp''
 service specification; see services(5).
```

and a scan through `ftpd.conf(5)` shows no obvious means to fiddle with the listen port (as opposed to the data port, which is different) so let's see if we can modify the `services` file, which is probably a bad idea.

```
$ sudo perl -i.oops -pe 's/^(ftp\s+21)/${1}21/' /etc/services
$ grep 2121 /etc/services
ftp              2121/udp     # File Transfer [Control]
ftp              2121/tcp     # File Transfer [Control]
scientia-ssdb   2121/udp    # SCIENTIA-SSDB
scientia-ssdb   2121/tcp    # SCIENTIA-SSDB
nupaper-ss      12121/tcp   # NuPaper Session Service
nupaper-ss      12121/udp   # NuPaper Session Service
$
```

And with this horrible, horrible kluge effected we now start `ftpd`... (this is on a 10.11.6 system which has `ftpd` installed by default under `/usr/libexec`)

```
$ /usr/libexec/ftpd -lnDr -P 50001
$
```

And it is running as not-root at the not-`21` port:

```
$ pgrep -lf ftpd
35258 /usr/libexec/ftpd -lnDr -P 50001
$ lsof -P -p 35258 | grep 2121
ftpd    35258 jhqdoe    4u   IPv4 0x817b7cd1effd8d7f       0t0      TCP *:2121 (LISTEN)
ftpd    35258 jhqdoe    5u   IPv6 0x817b7cd1effa3107       0t0      TCP *:2121 (LISTEN)
$
```

Whether this works or not I dunno; [do you really need FTP](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie)?

To undo this change, `sudo mv /etc/services.oops /etc/services`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't realize that there's a difference between the data port and the listen port -- what is the difference exactly, anyway? Also, nice job on allowing an undo of this change via `sudo mv /etc/services.oops /etc/services`. And no, I don't really need FTP for what I'm doing; I'm actually trying to write a script for the homebrew package manager and homebrew doesn't let you get super-user access, so I wanted to know if I could test the package without super-user privileges.

Comment: FTP is a strange old protocol that uses one port (21) that clients connect to and another port (20) that the server connects to the client from, unless you use passive mode ftp (on account of NAT and firewalls that put a halt to the now strange server-connects-to-client thing)